# react router v4 и history.push в саге

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать history.push в react router v4 в саге.
Знаю, что есть возможность сделать history.push из компонента с помощью this.props.history.push через withRouter, но этот вариант не подходит.

Пока ближе всего вот этот вариант, но он почему-то не работает...

```
// history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory();

//index.js
import history from './history.js;'
...
<BrowserRouter history={history}>

//sagas.js
import history from './history.js;'
...
history.push('/');
```

Url в адресной строке меняется, но переход не осуществляется.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам. 
Я импортировал

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

А надо было

```
import { Router } from 'react-router';
```

Соответственно рабочий вариант такой:

```
    // history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory();

//index.js
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import history from './history.js;'
...
<Router history={history}>

//sagas.js
import history from './history.js;'
...
history.push('/');
```

Comment: А у тебя точно `V4` Реакт роутера?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, Точно. `"react-router": "^4.1.1", "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2"`

Answer (score 0):

В приложении React с использованием Contex
Можно использовать хук:

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();
```

обновление страницы после использования `history.push('/')` задается в

```
\<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>

\</BrowserRouter>
```